# MySQL - Search Query between DATE_SUB() AND DATE_SUB() Error

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am trying to do a search query (using pdo php and mysql) between a date range which is between (date-7days) and (date-1day) using DATE_SUB() on both so for example:

```
end_date is 2013-03-26
search between 2013-03-19 and 2013-03-25 `
```

The below query however is using the first date_sub(7 day interval) but ignoring the second (date_sub(1 day interval) so its searching between 2013-03-19 and 2013-03-26.

```
$sevd_query = " 
    SELECT 
        booking_id,
        DATE_FORMAT(start_date, '%e/%c') AS s_d,
        DATE_FORMAT(end_date, '%e/%c') AS e_d
    FROM 
        bsi_bookings as bb 
    INNER JOIN 
        bsi_reservation as br ON bb.booking_id=br.bookings_id
    WHERE 
        bc.c_id=:c_id AND
       :day BETWEEN DATE_SUB(bb.end_date, INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND DATE_SUB(bb.end_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
";
```

Can anyone please help? I've been trying to fix this for a week now with no luck

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: no error message - it's just the ouput of the query is not matching as from the output i then display a specific status on my calendar day - but i can see the output is searching to the 26 not 25 - is there anything wrong with doing a search between 2 date_sub()'s?

Comment: @odd_duck does it actually select `bb.end_date`s that are after 1 day ago?

Comment: @ExplosionPills sorry to sound stupid but could you expand on what you mean??

Answer (score 0):

The clause:

```
:day BETWEEN DATE_SUB(bb.end_date, INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND
             DATE_SUB(bb.end_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

can be expressed as:

```
day >= (end_date - 7) AND
day <= (end_date - 1)
```

which can be rewritten as:

```
(day + 7) >= end_date AND
(day + 1) <= end_date
```

which is the same as:

```
end_date <= (day + 7) AND
end_date >= (day + 1)
```

which is also:

```
end_date >= (day + 1) AND
end_date <= (day + 7)
```

which can also be written as:

```
end_date BETWEEN (day + 1) AND (day + 7)
```

which I don't think is what you want.

Try this instead:

```
SELECT 
    booking_id,
    DATE_FORMAT(start_date, '%e/%c') AS s_d,
    DATE_FORMAT(end_date, '%e/%c') AS e_d
FROM 
    bsi_bookings as bb 
INNER JOIN 
    bsi_reservation as br ON bb.booking_id=br.bookings_id
WHERE 
    bc.c_id=:c_id AND
    bb.end_date BETWEEN :day - INTERVAL 7 DAY AND :day - INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

If the `end_date` field is indexed, this will allow the index to be used.

An index will not be used if the field to be searched is contained inside a function.

Comment: this is still not working for me Ross - is it just me or is the above taking the days off the day - not the end_date which is what i need (not to sound rude!)

Comment: I'm confused by your question. If you are substituting `2013-03-26` for the `:day` parameter, then you want to find all record where `end_date` is between `2013-03-19` and `2013-03-25`, correct? If so, the above query should work for you, and if not, then the problem lies somewhere else in your code.